# How to permanently set Tensorflow as Keras primary backend?

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, keras, theano

I have installed Tensorflow and Keras by Anaconda (Conda Forge's packages) on Windows. This kind of installation has set Theano as primary backend, so I have checked the `keras.json` file, surprisingly it has set Tensorflow as the main backend. Furthermore, if I try to remove Theano's installation, Keras stop working. I am supposing that each time I run Keras, it override the *json* file.
How could I permanently set Tensorflow as primary backend?

Comment: Where is the keras.json file located?

Comment: @rmeertens I can access it by _%USERPROFILE%/.keras/keras.json_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows,
Try launching the Anaconda prompt from start -> Anaconda* -> Anaconda prompt

*Anaconda followed by your version, for me it is Anaconda3 (64-bit)

Check whether you can see the below as the first line

**set "KERAS_BACKEND=theano"**

In this case, by default you can go to the below directory (If you have set a custom install directory you might have to navigate there)

**C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\etc\conda\activate.d**

and open the **keras_activate** batch file using notepad

Inside the file edit the line saying

**set "KERAS_BACKEND=theano"** to
**set "KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow"**

You are set to use Keras with tensorflow backend.

Answer (score 0):

As the question ages with time, for anybody coming across this now, the suggestion will be to use tensorflow.keras which is available since TensorFlow 1.15

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras